# Spark Scala: How to pass multiple selected columns to a function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to select a few columns (dynamically) from a dataframe to create an id out of it (maybe with sha256).

I don't know how to select a few columns, convert it to a map of column `Name` and `Value` to send to a function.

Here is the code that does not work

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val df = Seq(
    ("Java", "20000", "Compiled"), 
    ("Python", "100000", "Interpreted"), 
    ("Scala", "3000", "Compiled")).
    toDF("language","users_count","type")

val neededColumns = Array("language","type")

def GenerateId(map:Map[String,String]) =
{
    val builder = StringBuilder.newBuilder
    for((k,v) <- map) {
        builder.append(k)
        builder.append("=")
        builder.append(value)
    }
    sha2(builder.toString(), 256)
}

df.withColumn("id", GenerateId(df.columns.map(col)));
```

By selecting the `neededColumns` from the dataframe and sending to a function the desired output is

```text
| language | users_count | type       | id    |
| -------- | ----------- |------------|-------|
| Java     | 20000       |Compiled    | hexid |
| Python   | 100000      |Interpreted | hexid |
| Scala    | 3000        |Compiled    | hexid |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `contact` function to build the string column you want to pass to `sha2` like this:

```
def GenerateId(cols: Seq[String]) = {
  val concatExpr = concat_ws(",", cols.map(c => concat(lit(s"$c="), col(c))): _*)
  sha2(concatExpr, 256)
}

df.withColumn("id", GenerateId(neededColumns)).show(false)

//+--------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
//|language|users_count|type       |id                                                              |
//+--------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
//|Java    |20000      |Compiled   |5322d4f18b5f6b1330e2f2096bdfbdfdcc1dc7ea678982c35a424d3be3077e58|
//|Python  |100000     |Interpreted|cabdf1501324922d11f4281628c77cf983c219e5f123764598793baf1a96488a|
//|Scala   |3000       |Compiled   |4cc0da85338aa336c42dcd101daca71c6571aa12b1f752799fc7db1652a38d63|
//+--------+-----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Behind the scenes:

```
val concatExpr = concat_ws(",", neededColumns.map(c => concat(lit(s"$c="), col(c))): _*)
df.withColumn("map", concatExpr).withColumn("id", sha2(col("map"), 256)).show(false)

//+--------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
//|language|users_count|type       |map                             |id                                                              |
//+--------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
//|Java    |20000      |Compiled   |language=Java,type=Compiled     |5322d4f18b5f6b1330e2f2096bdfbdfdcc1dc7ea678982c35a424d3be3077e58|
//|Python  |100000     |Interpreted|language=Python,type=Interpreted|cabdf1501324922d11f4281628c77cf983c219e5f123764598793baf1a96488a|
//|Scala   |3000       |Compiled   |language=Scala,type=Compiled    |4cc0da85338aa336c42dcd101daca71c6571aa12b1f752799fc7db1652a38d63|
//+--------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Spent way too many hours tying to get this and your solution has some magic I don't understand. How is col() able to get the values out of cols that is just  a string Seq. neededColumns is an array, why did Scala not give type mismatch when passing to a func with Seq input? If you know a book and chapter, I can go read up. Thanks again. Your code worked perfectly for me.